# Trying to understand REDIS Monitor command

Tags: redis, monitor

I'm trying to understand [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR) command that is available in Redis and how can I use effectively to determine the load of my application. What I don't understand is how do I read the information that is being shown on the CLI. Like, I know that the number before the IP Address is the 'DB Index' but what can I infer from that number?

Example that is available on [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR) is:.

```
$ redis-cli monitor
1339518083.107412 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "keys" "*"
1339518087.877697 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "dbsize"
1339518090.420270 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "set" "x" "6"
1339518096.506257 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
1339518099.363765 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "del" "x"
1339518100.544926 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
```

I'm unable to understand the significance of '1339518083.107412'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first part is the timestamp in the form seconds.microseconds.

Comment: Then how is this data useful in monitoring?

Comment: You can count the number of commands over a duration, aggregate their types etc.

Comment: So I am assuming that the timestamp shown is the one at which command started executing and the delta between the first and the next timestamp is the time taken to execute the first command. Is it correct?

Comment: @user95025 only if the next command was processed immediately after the first one...

Answer (score 0):

The first part is the number of seconds and microseconds since 1970/1/1 (The Unix epoch). So if you want to extract the time, you do this:

```
new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddSeconds(seconds).AddMilliseconds(microsecods/1000).ToLocalTime()
```

or you can do this to parse the whole line:

```
var match = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<seconds>\d+)\.(?<microsec>\d+) (?<client>\[[\d\.\s:]+?\]) \""(?<command>\w+?)\""");
var sec = long.Parse(match.Groups["seconds"].Value);
var mic = long.Parse(match.Groups["microsec"].Value);
var rest = line.Substring(match.Groups["command"].Index + match.Groups["command"].Length + 1).Trim();
var command = match.Groups["command"].Value,
var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(sec).AddMilliseconds(mic / 1000).ToLocalTime()
```